# Hexagonal section numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, hexagonal-grid

### Introduction

Let's draw some regular hexagons formed by hexagonal tiles, marking the vertices of the tiles with dots. Then we will count the number of dots.

```
size 1: 6 dots
 . .
.   .
 . .

size 2: 24 dots
    . .
 . .   . .
.   . .   .
 . .   . .
.   . .   .
 . .   . .
    . .

size 3: 54 dots
       . .
    . .   . .
 . .   . .   . .
.   . .   . .   .
 . .   . .   . .
.   . .   . .   .
 . .   . .   . .
.   . .   . .   .
 . .   . .   . .
    . .   . .
       . .
```

Now, divide the hexagon into six identical sections, and keep the tiles that are needed to cover some of the sections. We still count the dots (vertices of the tiles) on the result.

```
size 3, one section: 22 dots
       . .
    . .   . .
 . .   . .   . .
.   . .   . .   .
 . .   @ @   . .
.   . @   @ @   .
 . .   @ @   @ @
.   . @   @ @   @
 . .   @ @   @ @
    . @   @ @
       @ @

size 3, two sections: 30 dots (38 and 46 dots for 3 and 4 sections respectively)
       . .
    . .   . .
 . .   . .   # #
.   . .   # #   #
 . .   @ @   # #
.   . @   @ @   #
 . .   @ @   @ @
.   . @   @ @   @
 . .   @ @   @ @
    . @   @ @
       @ @

size 3, five sections: 53 dots
       $ $
    * $   $ $
 * *   $ $   # #
*   * $   # #   #
 * *   @ @   # #
+   * @   @ @   #
 + +   @ @   @ @
+   + @   @ @   @
 + +   @ @   @ @
    . @   @ @
       @ @
```

Let's define \$H(n,k)\$ as the number of dots in the diagram of size \$n\$ with \$k\$ sections. It is guaranteed that \$1 \le n\$ and \$1 \le k \le 6\$.

### Challenge

Given the values of \$n\$ and \$k\$, calculate \$H(n,k)\$.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

The following is the table of values for small \$n\$:

```
     | k=1 k=2 k=3 k=4 k=5 k=6
-----+------------------------
n=1  |   6   6   6   6   6   6
n=2  |  13  16  19  22  24  24
n=3  |  22  30  38  46  53  54
n=4  |  33  48  63  78  92  96
n=5  |  46  70  94 118 141 150
n=6  |  61  96 131 166 200 216
n=7  |  78 126 174 222 269 294
n=8  |  97 160 223 286 348 384
n=9  | 118 198 278 358 437 486
n=10 | 141 240 339 438 536 600
n=11 | 166 286 406 526 645 726
n=12 | 193 336 479 622 764 864
```

\$H(n,1)\$ is equal to [A028872(n+2)](https://oeis.org/A028872). \$H(n,2)\$ is equal to [A054000(n+1)](https://oeis.org/A054000). \$H(n,6)\$ is equal to [A033581(n)](https://oeis.org/A033581). OEIS doesn't have the other three columns. Each column has its own formula, except for \$H(1,5)\$ :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda n,k:k*n*n+(4*n-k+2-k/5%n)*(k<6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7LCsIwFET3/YrZlOTmofShQtEvUReVWq3R21K6EfrvMRVFBN3MYobDme4@nFtOfb3Z@Wt5O1Ql2LjCKVasZa7YOp1aN1/ETEq69ZJ81zc8SAFghICGELNL27DcijirQhPDoW77kA2jL/l0lInBivZE0Yu11uonagUU0pyiCeAvIMmoiIC37SNJq8nBBmIU5oe9lmFz9OdDeOEf)

Not sure about its correctness. But it at least passed all testcases.

- -2 bytes by dingledooper
- -5 bytes by xnor

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: I think `k*(n>1)/5` can be shortened to `1%n*k/5`.

Comment: [Does this work?](https://tio.run/##dY7LCsIwFET3/YrZlOTmofShQtEvUReVWq3R21K6EfrvMRVFBN3MYobDme4@nFtOfb3Z@Wt5O1Ql2LjCKVasZa7YOp3aJGbl5gtS0q2X5Lu@4UEKACMENISYXdqG5VbEWRWaGA5124dsGH3Jp6NMDFa0J4perLVWP1EroJDmFE0AfwFJRkUEvG0fSVpNDjYQozA/7LUMm6M/H8IL/wA "Python 2 – Try It Online") It seems like the `6*n*n` case  in the `min` happens only for `k=6`. Haven't golfed it yet.

Comment: It looks like you can do `k/5%n` for `1%n*k/5`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 75 bytes

```
≔⁻²⪪024420¹ε≔⁻²⪪343101¹δＮθＦＮＦθ«Ｊ×κ§ε⊖ι×κ§δ⊖ιＦ⊕κ«ＧＨV→^←².Ｍ§ε⊕ι§δ⊕ι»»≔ＬＫＡζ⎚Ｉζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNT4MwFD/DX9Fwek2q4cvLdiLz4MxmiC4elyC8QUNpGS1TZ/a3Y1lcJC4emva99/vqy6usy1UmhiHRmpcS1lz2GkJGXlrBDXh@GMeh7zESUMoI0rn7DzCKo8APLsDCApey7c1T37xhB3tb71RHYNqklJx7e0q@XOexb9qNgg1vUEPNSGKWssAPQEbuMe@wQWmwAE5H/StUcY2yls6P5@@gpmczJ1Xis1TyQQmh3mH2ysjsmZeVsffWnhXu7NP@zrv1Rh1nrQ4Ik0hTTT4mmgT5Mxv5J/d0WdwKZWkqSBHrRAgYuUcLWQjM7ErmbtpxaWCRaQNHyx2GiNwNNwfxDQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as size and sections. Explanation: Far too long because it doesn't try to use a formula, but guarantees 100% correct answers.

```
≔⁻²⪪024420¹ε≔⁻²⪪343101¹δ
```

Create displacement vectors for each of the six hexagonal directions.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the size.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop over each section.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over each size.

```
Ｊ×κ§ε⊖ι×κ§δ⊖ι
```

Start each row of hexagons one step further away from the middle.

```
Ｆ⊕κ«
```

Loop over each row.

```
ＧＨV→^←².
```

Draw a hexagon. (This hexagon is slightly horizontally compressed compared to the one in the question, as it made it easier to draw a six-dotted hexagon.)

```
Ｍ§ε⊕ι§δ⊕ι
```

Move to the next hexagon in the row.

```
»»≔ＬＫＡζ
```

Count the number of dots.

```
⎚Ｉζ
```

Clear the canvas and output the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>38</strike> 36 bytes

```javascript
n=>k=>n*n*k+(k<6&&n*4+2-k-(n>1&k>4))
```

-2 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BasMwEEX3OsVggpGsyGBHTReOdYlsu4hI5JDKjIQsunF8dmfcNgOPv/nvM9/2x07X9IhZYbi5dXQZBuhX7I3vDVZYecn96ViWWGnZKq84mqb0RgvxW56ghwvQPYmGaIkDoYkP4sgUndzNhSrq5KKzmbdaLJeObX4knzYMTHUO55weeOeijvZ2zjZlrvdQQCE6NoTEtz5Sv@koTtAcKKUUMDOgDUmPfOFujhzF8qR5gLfk/yRP0ifF2/m3Ih9I4V6IzVnYwq4BpzC6egx3PolufQE)

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY5BasMwEEX3OsVggpGsyGBHTReOdYlsu4hI5JDKjIQsunF8dmfcNgOPv/nvM9/2x07X9IhZYbi5dXQZBuhX7I3vDVZYecn96ViWWGnZKq84mqb0RgvxW56ghwvQPYmGaIkDoYkP4sgUndzNhSrq5KKzmbdaLJeObX4knzYMTHUO55weeOeijvZ2zjZlrvdQQCE6NoTEtz5Sv@koTtAcKKUUMDOgDUmPfOFujhzF8qR5gLfk/yRP0ifF2/m3Ih9I4V6IzVnYwq4BpzC6egx3PolufQE)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Port of [*@tsh*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231632/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

The inputs are in the order \$n,k\$.

```
4*²D5÷¹%ÆÌ²6‹*¹n²*+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//zQqwrJENcO3wrklw4bDjMKyNuKAuSrCuW7Csior//8xMAoz) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m6hdmaOTqF6mUZ3t4v042kFB41DZJQcne77@JVqSL6eHtfqqH2w73RJo9atip5ZcXqaX9X@c/AA).

Or alternatively:

```
n*²6‹iU5÷¹%-¹4*αX2O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//24qwrI24oC5aVU1w7fCuSUtwrk0Ks6xWDJP//8xMAoz) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m6hdmaOTqF6mUZ3t4v042kFB41DZJQck@8vAEv/95WpFmjxp2ZoaaHt7up6rrZ6J1bmOEkf//Wp3/AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
4*                   # Multiply the first (implicit) input `n` by 4
  ²D                 # Push the second input `k` twice
    5÷               # Integer-divide the second one by 5
      ¹%             # And then modulo it by the first input `n`
        Æ            # Reduce all three values on the stack by subtracting
         Ì           # Increase it by 2
          ²6‹        # Check if the second input `k` is smaller than 6
             *       # Multiply this to the earlier value
              ¹n     # Push the first input `n` squared
                ²*   # Multiply it to the second input
                  +  # And add the two together
                     # (after which the result is output implicitly)

n                    # Square the first (implicit) input `n`
 *                   # Multiply it to the second (implicit) input `k`
  ²6‹i               # If the second input `k` is smaller than 6:
      U              #  Pop the earlier value and save it in variable `X`
       5÷            #  Integer-divide the second (implicit) input `k` by 5
         ¹%          #  And then modulo it by the first input `n`
           -         #  Subtract it from the second (implicit) input `k`
            ¹4*      #  Push the first input `n`, and multiply it by 4
               α     #  Get the absolute difference between the two values
                X    #  Push `X` back to the stack
                 2   #  Push 2
                  O  #  And sum the three values on the stack together
                     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```